# Closest point projection of a 3D point to 3D triangles with numpy/scipy

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, geometry

How would one calculate the closest projections of a point to N triangles using numpy/scipy?

Right now I would make a function to calculate a projection to a single triangle, [basically this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/552906-closest-point-on-triangle/), then iterate across the entire array of triangles. But before I set off to do this I was wondering if there's already a solution built in scipy. Something like:

```
# DREAMY PSEUDOCODE
import numpy as np
N_TRIANGLES = 1000

point = np.random.rand(3) * 100 #random 3d point
triangles = np.random.rand(N_TRIANGLES,3,3) * 100 #array of triangles

from scipy.spatial import pointToTriangles
projections = pointToTriangles(point,triangles)
```

Here's a picture to help you visualize:

[image: example of point projection]

In the image above, the red dot in the middle is my query "point", the blue dots are the vertices of each triangles as define in the "triangles" np.array(). The green dots represent the result i want. They're the closest projections of "point" onto the defined triangles, and i wish to get this info back as an array of points.

cheers!

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking for? In your example, what should `projections` contain?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by *projections of "point" to the triangle's surface*. If I have a point and a triangle in 3D space then there are infinitely many lines I could draw connecting the point to the surface of the triangle. Could you maybe find/draw a diagram, or at least give an example with real numbers?

Comment: @ali_m sorry, i'm looking for the closest projection to a point on triangles.

Comment: You can project the point onto the plane of each triangle, is that what you want? Or do you also want to find the closest point in the triangle to that projected point?

Comment: @Jaime I want the projections to be in the triangles. Projecting to the triangle planes is fairly straightforward to do.

Comment: Well, projection typically happens along a well defined direction. If it's not the triangle's plane normal, you need to define which one to project along, or your problem is undefined.

Comment: @Jaimei added a picture to help visualize

Comment: @Fnord - CGAL can be a bit of a pain to install, but for 3D operations such as this, it has what you want as well as several other very useful operations.  As an example that does more or less exactly what you want: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-swig-bindings/blob/master/examples/python/AABB_triangle_3_example.py  Have a look at the last few lines in the example.

Comment: @Fnord, I checked the reference you cited in your question, I am using the same code/formula (and it works well). I do not understand what is exactly your question ? How to translate it in Python ? (seems quite easy). For an array of triangles, just call it in a loop. Now if you have many many triangles and want only the nearest point among all triangles, you will need a more elaborate data structure (AABBTree), is this the problem ?

Comment: @BrunoLevy iterating over a large array of millions of triangles will be too slow. Fortunately the code in the example I cited can be rewritten to leverage numpy's vectorized arithmetic operations, which would speed it up. But before I set out to do this, I was hoping this was an already solved problem. Akin to someone asking about writing a nearest neighbor kd tree function from scratch when there is scipy.spatial.cKDtree at their disposal. CGAL sounds like an interesting option if it's fast.

Comment: @JoeKington thank you! I'll investigate CGAL later tomorrow. Have you used it yourself? Is it pretty fast?

Comment: @JoeKington CGAL is promising but unfortunately only lets me query the closest triangle when i pass it the triangle soup. I wish it just gave me all the projections, right now i have to create a tree per triangle and query. which gets very slow. But thanks for the suggestion!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code i came up with. I couldn't find anything in scipy that could help me directly, and this solution is about 2x faster than querying CGAL. It doesn't handle collapsed triangles, but that could be fixed by checking edge lengths and return the closest point on the longest edge instead.

```
import numpy as np

def pointsToTriangles(points,triangles):
    
    with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
        
        # Unpack triangle points
        p0,p1,p2 = np.asarray(triangles).swapaxes(0,1)
                
        # Calculate triangle edges
        e0 = p1-p0
        e1 = p2-p0
        a = np.einsum('...i,...i', e0, e0)
        b = np.einsum('...i,...i', e0, e1)
        c = np.einsum('...i,...i', e1, e1)
        
        # Calculate determinant and denominator
        det = a*c - b*b
        invDet = 1. / det
        denom = a-2*b+c
        
        # Project to the edges
        p  = p0-points[:,np.newaxis]
        d = np.einsum('...i,...i', e0, p)
        e = np.einsum('...i,...i', e1, p)
        u = b*e - c*d
        v = b*d - a*e
        
        # Calculate numerators
        bd = b+d
        ce = c+e
        numer0 = (ce - bd) / denom
        numer1 = (c+e-b-d) / denom
        da = -d/a
        ec = -e/c
        
        
        # Vectorize test conditions
        m0 = u + v < det
        m1 = u < 0
        m2 = v < 0
        m3 = d < 0
        m4 = (a+d > b+e)
        m5 = ce > bd
        
        t0 =  m0 &  m1 &  m2 &  m3
        t1 =  m0 &  m1 &  m2 & ~m3
        t2 =  m0 &  m1 & ~m2
        t3 =  m0 & ~m1 &  m2
        t4 =  m0 & ~m1 & ~m2
        t5 = ~m0 &  m1 &  m5
        t6 = ~m0 &  m1 & ~m5
        t7 = ~m0 &  m2 &  m4
        t8 = ~m0 &  m2 & ~m4
        t9 = ~m0 & ~m1 & ~m2
        
        u = np.where(t0, np.clip(da, 0, 1), u)
        v = np.where(t0, 0, v)
        u = np.where(t1, 0, u)
        v = np.where(t1, 0, v)
        u = np.where(t2, 0, u)
        v = np.where(t2, np.clip(ec, 0, 1), v)
        u = np.where(t3, np.clip(da, 0, 1), u)
        v = np.where(t3, 0, v)
        u *= np.where(t4, invDet, 1)
        v *= np.where(t4, invDet, 1)
        u = np.where(t5, np.clip(numer0, 0, 1), u)
        v = np.where(t5, 1 - u, v)
        u = np.where(t6, 0, u)
        v = np.where(t6, 1, v)
        u = np.where(t7, np.clip(numer1, 0, 1), u)
        v = np.where(t7, 1-u, v)
        u = np.where(t8, 1, u)
        v = np.where(t8, 0, v)
        u = np.where(t9, np.clip(numer1, 0, 1), u)
        v = np.where(t9, 1-u, v)
        
        
        # Return closest points
        return (p0.T +  u[:, np.newaxis] * e0.T + v[:, np.newaxis] * e1.T).swapaxes(2,1)
```

Some test data projecting 100 points to 10k triangles:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cProfile
    
    N_TRIANGLES = 10**4 # 10k triangles
    N_POINTS    = 10**2 # 100 points
    points      = np.random.random((N_POINTS,3,)) * 100
    triangles   = np.random.random((N_TRIANGLES,3,3,)) * 100
    
    cProfile.run("pointsToTriangles(points,triangles)") # 54 function calls in 0.320 seconds
```

This will quickly become a memory hog, so when dealing with large data sets it's probably better to iterate over either points or triangles one at a time.

Comment: Is this code roughly following the algorithm described at http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistancePoint3Triangle3.pdf, or it is something different? [edit: I now see that it is, but is vectorised over many input triangles] What are the shapes of the inputs ?

Comment: I made a few tweaks to the code so it can handle an array of points projected over an array of triangles. If you look at the updated example you'll see the input shapes.